# Set a sub-matrix to a value using for-loops in Python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, matrix, nested

I have been pulling my hair out on what should be a simple python problem but so far have not been having any luck seeing my mistake. I have this code that should initialize a 10 x 10 matrix to all zeros and then set a sub-matrix to ones but it is not behaving as I expect.

Here is my code simplified as much as possible:

```
# Initialize matrix to all zeros
xs = 10
ys = 10
lights = [[0]*xs]*ys

# Set a 3 x 3 portion of the matrix to all ones
for y in range(3, 6):
    for x in range(5, 8):
        lights[y][x] = 1

# Print confusing results
count = 0
for y in range(ys):
    for x in range(xs):
        print(lights[y][x], end=' ')
        count += lights[y][x]
    print()
print(count)
```

I expect this result:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What I get is this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
```

Why are all the rows set the same? Thanks in advance for any insight.